# add 2 classpath in 1 command line

Tags: java, command-line, classpath, command-prompt

I have problems to compile this, im trying to add 2 classpath but it fail

```
javac -cp C:\xampp\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar : C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\examen\WEB-INF\classes ErabiltzaileKontuaEzabatuServlet.java
```

in the first i add the .jar, and the second is for the classes inside that folder.

Comment: the separator for windows is ; I believe

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to notice is the space around `:` that should not exist. The other thing is the classpath separator. Judging by the `C:\` you are using Windows, so the path separator is a semicolon (`;`) instead of a colon (`:`).

The following should do:

```
javac -cp C:\xampp\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\examen\WEB-INF\classes ErabiltzaileKontuaEzabatuServlet.java
```